# Convert beamer code to article / book code

Tags: beamer, conversion, article, books

I have seen in multiple sites about conversions between exporting a beamer file as an article pdf such as https://gitlab.com/benoitldr/beamerarticle-teacher.

The issue I have is that I created a lot of beamer slides, about 3 years back, but now I want to fully convert them into latex article class or latex book class, whichever is simpler.

Below is a sample code that I had done previously. As you can see, back then, I thought that doing a lot of `\uncover` would be a good idea, but at this point, trying to change all of them away is pretty much of a hassle.

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries}

\title{Primes \& Prime Factorisation}
\subtitle{Factors \& Multiples}  
\author[Eugene]{Eugene}
\institute[SS]{\normalsize{Singapore School}}
\date{\today} 

\section*{Singapore School}
\subsection*{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\subsection*{TOC}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table Of Contents}
\tableofcontents[pausesubsections]
\end{frame} 

\section{Recall}


\subsection{Factors}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}\Large{Recall}\end{center} \vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{center}\Large{\red{Factors}}\end{center}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Factors}
\begin{block}{Recall: Factors}
\uncover<2->{\alert{Factors} are numbers that can divide the original number.\\
\uncover<3->{\footnotesize Tip: Smaller or equal to original number}}
\end{block}

\uncover<3->{\begin{exampleblock}{Example}}
\uncover<4->{Factors of 16:} \uncover<5->{1}\uncover<6->{, 2}\uncover<7->{, 4}\uncover<8->{, 8}\uncover<9->{, 16}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\subsection{Multiples}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}\Large{Recall}\end{center} \vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{center}\Large{\red{Multiples}}\end{center}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multiples}
\begin{block}{Recall: Multiples}
\uncover<2->{\alert{Multiples} are numbers that can be divided by the original number.\\
\uncover<3->{\footnotesize Tip: Bigger or equal to original number}}
\end{block}

\uncover<3->{\begin{exampleblock}{Example}}
\uncover<4->{Multiples of 16:} \uncover<5->{16}\uncover<6->{, 32}\uncover<7->{, 48}\uncover<8->{, 64, $\dots$}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}


\section{Concept}

\subsection{Primes}


\begin{frame}

\begin{center}\Large{Concept}\end{center} \vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{center}\Large{\red{Primes}}\end{center}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Primes}
\begin{block}{Concept: Primes}
\uncover<2->{\alert{Primes} are whole numbers with only 2 factors, 1 and itself.\\
\uncover<3->{\footnotesize Tip: Must be greater than 1}}
\end{block}
\uncover<3->{\begin{exampleblock}{Examples}}
\uncover<4->{Examples: 2}\uncover<5->{, 3}\uncover<6->{, 5}\uncover<7->{, 7}\uncover<8->{, 11}\uncover<9->{, 13, $\dots$}\\
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Composite Numbers}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}\Large{Concept}\end{center} \vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{center}\Large{\red{Composite Numbers}}\end{center}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Composite Numbers}
\begin{block}{Concept: Composite Numbers}
\uncover<2->{\alert{Composite numbers} are whole numbers with more than 2 factors.}
\end{block}
\uncover<3->{\begin{exampleblock}{Examples}}
\uncover<4->{Examples: 4}\uncover<5->{, 6}\uncover<6->{, 8}\uncover<7->{, 9}\uncover<8->{, 10}\uncover<9->{, 12, $\dots$}\\
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\subsection*{Questions}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}\Large{Concept}\end{center} \vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{center}\Large{\red{Questions}}\end{center}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Questions}
\begin{exampleblock}{Concept: Questions}
Classify the following numbers into primes or composite numbers:
\begin{enumerate}
\item 20
\item 29
\item 1
\item 37
\item 0
\end{enumerate}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Index Notation \& Prime Factorisation}


\begin{frame}

\begin{center}\Large{Concept}\end{center} \vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{center}\Large{\red{Index Notation \& Prime Factorisation}}\end{center}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Index Notation}
\begin{block}{Concept: Index Notation}
\uncover<2->{\alert{Index notation} means expressing the product of terms using powers.}
\end{block}
\uncover<3->{\begin{exampleblock}{Example}}
\uncover<4->{Write the index notation of $7\times7\times7$:}\uncover<5->{ $7^3$}\\
\uncover<6->{Write the index notation of $2\times2\times2\times2\times2$:}\uncover<7->{$= 2^5$}\\
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Prime Factorisation}
\begin{block}{Concept: Prime Factorisation}
\uncover<2->{\alert{Prime factorisation} means expressing a composite number as a product of its prime factors.}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Prime Factorisation}

\begin{exampleblock}{Example 1: Factor Tree }
\uncover<2->{Find the prime factorisation of 210.}\\



\uncover<3->{
\begin{align*}
210&=2\times 3\times 5\times 7
\end{align*}}


\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Prime Factorisation}

\begin{exampleblock}{Example 2: Factor Tree }
\uncover<2->{Find the prime factorisation of 140, leaving your answer in \textbf{index notation}.}\\

\uncover<3->{
\begin{align*}
140&=2^2\times 5\times 7
\end{align*}}

\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}



\section*{Conclusion}
\subsection*{Closure}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Closure}
\tableofcontents[pausesubsections]
\end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Would getting rid of the "uncover" commands be enough to solve this issue? You could apply a regular expression in any decent editor. What tools do you have available?

Comment: No, not really. There is still the frame, block and other things that latex article / book does not have. I'm actually using texshop on Mac and don't have any other tools available. I was just wondering if there was any way of converting it over to an article / book style otherwise my last resort is to manually change them individually till it fits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the package `beamerarticle` described in Section 21.2.1 of [this beamer manual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). It emulates the beamer specific commands when you use other document classes.

Exchange the first line of your file with these

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
```

Edit: Oh, and credit to [this blog](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.de/2010/08/getting-started-with-beamer-tips-and.html) for pointing in the right direction.